# RASA - How can i use max_event_history to avoid fetching large records from DB

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

We are running an app which uses Rasa on production from more than a year and we are using MariaDb for the DB store. Now for some users (`sender_id`) there are more than 4M+ records. Recently we have also seen the app taking more than 10GB+ of memory.

This could be happening because when the users with more than 4M+ records interact with our system we might be fetching all these 4M+ records into our app memory.

To solve this I’ve found that there is a field called `max_event_history`, but I’m not sure how to use this. Please guide me here as it is causing a huge problem in our production.

```py
tracker_store = SQLTrackerStore(domain=domain, dialect="mysql", host=self.tracker_store_host,
                                port=self.tracker_store_port, db=self.tracker_store_db,
                                username=self.tracker_store_user, password=self.tracker_store_password)
```

This is how we are configuring `tracker_store`. Does adding

```py
tracker_store.max_event_history = 100 after creating tracker_store
```

would work for me?

**Rasa Version** - `2.5.0`

Comment: have you set up your tracker store and the parameters in `endpoints.yml`?

Comment: no, parameters are in our properties file and tracker_store we have setup as shown in above code @aLoneStrider

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own Tracker Store class if you don't want to use Rasa various Tracker Stores. Then you need to add your setup to the `endpoints.yml` in this fashion:

```
tracker_store:
  type: path_to_your_module.Class
  url: your_url
  db: ""
  username: ""
  password: ""
  param_0: ""
  param_1: ""
```

Your class needs to inherit from the base class and implements constructor (also calls super), save, retrieve, and keys methods. You can set `max_event_history` in the methods and control the number of events in retrieve or maybe even save methods.

```
DialogueStateTracker.from_dict(sender_id, events, slots, max_event_history)
```

For details and documentation follow [Rasa doc](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/tracker-stores/).